# How to update JList and JTextfield with database HSQLDB?

Tags: java, swing

I use Eclipse and my database is hsqldb. I have a JFrame with 3 JPanel.

In my first JPanel, I have 3 JList, Category, Brands and Product.

In my database, I have a table 
category (id, name)
brands (id, name)
product (id, product, price, description, quantity + foreign key on category and Brands).

I started coding but I can not do that when I select one item in JList category and brand,  I have to bring up the result in product (one item or multiple) and when I select one item in Jlist Product, I have to bring up the result in the JPanel Informations (price, description and quantity).

Below the code of my IHM

```
package IHM;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

import Donnees.Categories;
import Donnees.CategoriesCellRenderer;
import Donnees.CategoriesListModel;
import Donnees.Marques;
import Donnees.MarquesCellRenderer;
import Donnees.MarquesListModel;
import Donnees.Produits;
import Donnees.ProduitsCellRenderer;
import Donnees.ProduitsListModel;
import Fabriques.FabCategories;
import Fabriques.FabMarques;

import java.awt.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Fenetre {

static Connection conn;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
        conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:file:BDD/bdd","sa","");

        FabCategories.getInstance().demarrerConnexion(conn);
        FabMarques.getInstance().demarrerConnexion(conn);

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Gestion des Produits");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container contentPane = f.getContentPane(); 
        contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2,3, 3));

        JPanelProduit jPanelProduit = new JPanelProduit();
        JPanelInformations jPanelInformations = new JPanelInformations();
        JPanelVentes jPanelVentes = new JPanelVentes();

        jPanelProduit.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        jPanelProduit.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        jPanelVentes.setBackground(Color.PINK);

        contentPane.add(jPanelProduit);
        contentPane.add(jPanelInformations);
        contentPane.add(jPanelVentes);

        f.setSize(700,700);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class JPanelProduit extends JPanel implements ListSelectionListener {

    public JPanelProduit() throws SQLException {
        JPanel panelProduit = new JPanel();
        setLayout(new GridLayout(5,2,5,5));

        String labelCat = "Categories";
        String labelMark = "Marques";    
        String labelProd = "Produits"; 

        JList<Categories> listCategories= new JList<Categories> ();
        JList<Marques> listMarques= new JList<Marques> ();
        JList<Produits> listProduits= new JList<Produits> ();

        JScrollPane listCategoriesScrollPane = new JScrollPane (listCategories);        

        add(new JLabel(labelCat));
        add(new JScrollPane(listCategoriesScrollPane));
        listCategories.setCellRenderer(new CategoriesCellRenderer());;
        listCategories.setModel(new CategoriesListModel());
        listCategories.addListSelectionListener((this));

        add(new JLabel(labelMark));
        JScrollPane listMarquesScrollPane = new JScrollPane (listMarques);        
        add(new JScrollPane(listMarquesScrollPane));
        listMarques.setCellRenderer(new MarquesCellRenderer());
        listMarques.setModel(new MarquesListModel());
        listMarques.addListSelectionListener(this);

        add(new JLabel(labelProd));
        JScrollPane listProduitScrollPane = new JScrollPane (listProduits);        
        add(new JScrollPane(listProduitScrollPane));
        listProduits.addListSelectionListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}

class JPanelInformations extends JPanel {

    public JPanelInformations() {
        //JPanel PanelInformation = new JPanel(); remove new instance of panel
        setLayout(new GridLayout(7,1,5,5)); 

        JLabel labelInfo = new JLabel ("INFORMATION");
        JLabel labelPrix = new JLabel ("Prix");
        JLabel labelDesc = new JLabel ("Description");    
        JLabel labelQuant = new JLabel ("Quantite");    
        JTextField fieldPrix = new JTextField (20); 
        JTextArea fieldDesc = new JTextArea (20, 20); 
        JTextField fieldQuantite = new JTextField (20); 

        add(labelInfo); //remove PanelInformation.
        add(labelPrix);//remove PanelInformation.
        add(fieldPrix);//remove PanelInformation.
        add(labelDesc);//remove PanelInformation.
        add(fieldDesc);//remove PanelInformation.
        add(labelQuant);//remove PanelInformation.
        add(fieldQuantite);//remove PanelInformation.
    }
}

class JPanelVentes extends JPanel {

    public JPanelVentes() {
        //JPanel PanelVentes = new JPanel(); remove the new instance of JPanel
        setLayout(new GridLayout(8,1,5,5));
        JLabel labelVendre = new JLabel ("VENDRE");
        JLabel labelQte = new JLabel ("Quantite");
        JLabel labelPromo = new JLabel ("Promotion");
        JLabel labelTot = new JLabel ("Total");    
        JTextField fieldQte = new JTextField (20); 
        JTextField fieldPromoEuros = new JTextField (20); 
        JTextField fieldPromoPourcent = new JTextField (20); 
        JTextField fieldTotal = new JTextField (20); 


        add (labelVendre); //remove PanelVentes
        add (labelQte);//remove PanelVentes
        add (fieldQte);//remove PanelVentes
        add (labelPromo);//remove PanelVentes
        add (fieldPromoEuros);//remove PanelVentes
        add (fieldPromoPourcent);//remove PanelVentes
        add (labelTot);//remove PanelVentes
        add (fieldTotal);//remove PanelVentes
    }
}
```

Comment: Get the row number of the selected row from the list and then with the cell number you can get the details in the cells as strings. Then you can pass those values to any text field or label as you want. Code on the click method of the table.

Comment: Where I have to put the code? I have in JPanel JPanelProduit, 3 addListSelectionListener ?

Comment: add the code in MouseClicked event.

Comment: have you used `MVC`?